# MySQL How to group by date with CASE statements as columns instead of rows

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery, pivot, case-statement

Not sure if I'm even asking this correctly.
I have a query that I am trying to display totals per each reason_id based on another tables qty value, but then group by months in the table where the reason_id exists.

My Query so far is:

```
select
month(f.c_date),
case when q.reason_id = 2 then sum(f.produced) else 0 end as 'LowM',
case when q.reason_id = 3 then sum(f.produced) else 0 end as 'LowP',
case when q.reason_id = 4 then sum(f.produced) else 0 end as 'LowSC',

from freeze f
inner join freezeq q on f.id = q.frz_id
inner join location l on f.t_id = l.id

where 1=1
and f.c_date like '%2018%'
group by q.reason_id, month(f.c_date);
```

I need to remove the "group by q.reason_id" but then of course the SUM values aren't separated.

I am trying to display the CASEs as columns and the SUM of the f.produced values, but group on the f.c_date.

I tried with sub queries a couple different ways, but can't seem to get it.

I appreciate any help the collective mind can give me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to use *condition aggregate function*, use `case when` in the `sum` function.

```
select
    month(f.c_date),
    sum(case when q.reason_id = 2 then f.produced) else 0 end) as 'LowM',
    sum(case when q.reason_id = 3 then f.produced else 0 end) as 'LowP',
    sum(case when q.reason_id = 4 then f.produced else 0 end) as 'LowSC'
from freeze f
inner join freezeq q on f.id = q.frz_id
inner join location l on f.t_id = l.id
where  f.c_date like '%2018%'
group by  month(f.c_date);
```

**NOTE**

I remove the  `1=1 and` because that no sence in your query.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info! That 100% helped.
Also, thank you for helping me understand the correct terminology to use here. 
Helps me a lot!
That where 1=1 is a bad habit of mine, then everything else is an AND for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about how to do *conditional aggregation*.

Move the aggregate to the outside of the condition. The conditional will return the scalar we want to aggregate (if the condition is satisfied) or return 0 or NULL (if the condition isn't satisfied). The the aggregate function will operate on the returned scalars.

Replace this:

```
  case when q.reason_id = 2 then sum(f.produced) else 0 end as 'LowM'
```

With this:

```
  SUM( CASE WHEN q.reason_id = 2 THEN f.produced ELSE 0 END ) AS `LowM`
```

---

Other notes:

If `c_date` is DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP datatype,

replace this condition:

```
    f.c_date LIKE '%2018%'
```

with

```
    f.c_date >= '2018-01-01'
AND f.c_date  < '2018-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

This will enable MySQL to make use of a range scan operation on a suitable index (if a suitable index is available.)

Using a `LIKE` comparison on a DATE will force MySQL to evaluate *every* row in the table, to convert every `c_date` value into a string, and doing the string comparison.

(We might like the optimizer to be "smart" enough to figure out the more efficient rewrite, but it just isn't that smart.)

---

The   `WHERE 1=1` doesn't have any impact on performance. We frequently see this in dynamically generated WHERE clauses; the application code can just append `AND whatever`, and not be cluttered up with a check to see if we need a `WHERE` keyword in place of the `AND` (for the first condition in the WHERE clause.)

Any newbies that are confused by the `WHERE 1=1` can be brought up to speed very easily.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!
Exactly what I was missing.
Also thanks for giving me the proper terminology to use and understand better what I'm doing.

Comment: Ah! Great! Performance is always a plus. Thank you for that extra hint. I will do that